# Android: onDisable doesn't work consistently

Tags: android, amazon-s3, notifications, device-admin

In my android application I want to send notification when admin mode is disabled. It's my code:

```
 public class DeviceAdminComponent extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

    public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) {
        sendNotificationToS3();

        return super.onDisableRequested(context, intent);
    }

    public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        sendNotificationToS3();

        super.onDisabled(context, intent);
    }

    private void sendNotificationToS3() {
        String notificationMsg = "blabla";

        S3ClientTransfer.sendNotification("myfilename.txt", notificationMsg);
    }
}
```

My AndroidManifex.xml:

```
. . .
<receiver
        android:name=".main.DeviceAdminComponent"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
    <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And my device_admin.xml

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <uses-policies>
        <limit-password />
        <reset-password />
        <force-lock />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

So, this code works but not consistently - it doesn't send notification always. For example, when I debug this code notification will be send otherwise not.

What do I miss?

Comment: please post your manifest also

Comment: @ManojPerumarath posted

Comment: Where's device admin XML

Comment: @ManojPerumarath posted also